# Проблема верстки сайта. Не увеличивается фон класса

Tags: вёрстка

Всем добрый день! 
Проблема: не могу увеличить автоматом желтое поле фона  “. content1”

```css
#wrapper { width: 84%; margin: auto; margin-top: -8px; height:100%;  background: #fff;   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #b1b1b1;  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #b1b1b1; position: relative;  min-height: 100%;
}
#content {float: left; width: 100%; position: relative; overflow: hidden; background: #FFF;}

#content .content1 {margin: 0 auto; width: 98%; height: 100%; position: relative; background: #E3E2C6; 
                   border-radius: 12px; margin-top: -5px; margin-bottom: 40px; display: block;}
#content .content1  .body3 {width:100%; padding-top: 1px; position: relative; display: block;}
#content .content1  .side-r2 {width:100%; height: 100%; text-align:left; position: relative; padding-bottom: 15px; display: block;}
#content .content1  .r2-img {float: left; background: #fff; margin-left: 40px; width: 40%; padding: 6px; border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;}
#content .content1  .r2-text { float: right; margin-right: 40px; margin-left: 5px; width: 45%; text-align: justify; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; margin-top: -17px;}
```

```html
<table id="wrapper">
 <div id="content">
  <div class="content1">
   <div class="body3">
    <h2>ЗАГОЛОВОК</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="side-r2"> <br>
    <div class="r2-img">
     <img src="images/main.jpg" alt="filler image">
    </div> 
    <div class="r2-text">
     <h4> ОБЫЧНЫЙ ТЕКСТ </h4>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</table>
```

В данном примере высота “.side-r2” очень узкая, хотя в него входят два дива “.r2-img” и “.r2-text”.
Можно конечно увеличить высоту фона “.content1” в пикселях, но это не вариант. Надо чтобы он полностью закрывал два дива “.body3” и “.side-r2” и был ниже текста и картинок.
Перепробовал много вариантов – никак не получается. В чем причина? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Блок не закрывает полностью из-за плавающих элементов. Чтобы исправить, надо добавить свойство **clear**. К примеру:

```
#content .content1::after {display:block; content: " "; clear:both;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qdufu34c/ результат с Вашим кодом.

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы! Опять забыл clear! Спасибо! Жаль репутации не хватает отметить Ваш ответ - правильным!

Comment: Галку поставить можно при любом уровне репутации.